# .net core build errors after Visual Studio update

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, fluentvalidation

I have updated Visual Studio to 16.10.1 version, and my once fully functioning project is now showing build errors, mainly relating to fluentValidation and JwtBearer.

Any advice how to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Have you done a Build-> Clean Solution ? Restart VS ?

Comment: What was your previous version? (Have you not updated in a while?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following methods:

1. Restart Visual Studio 2019.
2. Clan the project. Right click the Project, choose the "Clean" option, then click the "Build" option.
3. Clear the Nuget Package cache.

   [image]
4. Reinstall the related package.